# FadeTransition not showing

Tags: flutter, dart

[A video is better that a thousand of words](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/421445316617961502/608588333127565323/Android_Emulator_-_Pixel_3_XL_API_28_5554_2019-08-07_11-11-10.mp4)

I wanted a Fade transition when the info card builds
So this is what I did :

```dart
 Builder(
   builder:(context){ 
     return _currentItem == 1 ? FadeTransition(
       opacity: fadeAnimation,
         child: new HotelAdditionnalInfo(),
        )
        :
        FadeTransition(
         opacity: fadeAnimation,
         child: new FlightAdditionnalInfo(),
        )
       ;
     }
  )
```

and for the animation parameters:

```dart
class _BookingsState extends State<Bookings> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _currentItem = 0;
  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation fadeAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    fadeAnimation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(animationController);
    animationController.forward();
    super.initState();
  }
```

The animation doesn't show. I probably did something wrong, but I can't find out what :/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found a widget that can do the job :

```dart
AnimatedCrossFade(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            firstChild: new HotelAdditionnalInfo(),
            secondChild: new FlightAdditionnalInfo(),
            crossFadeState: _currentItem == 1 ? CrossFadeState.showFirst : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
          )
```

but it removed the shadows of my content.

before :
[image]
after : [image]

Does someone know if this widget needs a kind of container ?